# To delete the property value in Alfresco custom model

Tags: javascript, alfresco, yui, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I need to delete the node property in alfresco 5.0.d version. While trying to delete I am getting this below error:

> Web Script Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

The alfresco webscript file:

```
function main() {
  // Get the username 
  var userName = url.extension;
  // Get the agencycode
  var agencycode = args.agencycode;

  var path = '+PATH:"/app:company_home/*"';
  var cond = 'AND (TYPE:"cm:content")';
  var query = path + " " + cond;
  // get all nodes and properties
  var nodes = search.luceneSearch(query);
  logger.system.out(nodes);

  for each(var node in nodes)
  {
    * *// TODO checking the user exists**    

    if (node.properties["agency:agencyname"].indexOf(agencycode) != -1) {
      delete node.properties["agency:agencycode"];
      delete node.properties["agency:agencyname"];
      delete node.properties["agency:createDate"];
    }
  }

  model.success = true;
}

main();
```

In above script I'm getting the agency code and I'm iterating to check if the agency code matches, then I am deleting the node property.

Please help to resolve from this issue.

Comment: Can you post your webscript descriptor file? And have you ensured you've registered it for the same HTTP method as you're calling?

Comment: <!--customagencyDelete.delete.desc--><webscript>
   <shortname>Deleting the node Property</shortname>
   <description><![CDATA[
   Deleting the node and properties for given agencycode
   
   <br />
   <dl>
   <dt>agencycode </dt><dd>mandatory - agencycode</dd>
   </dl>
   
   ]]></description>
   <url>/api/customagencydelete</url>
   <format default="json">argument</format>
   <authentication>admin</authentication>
   <transaction>required</transaction>
   <lifecycle>limited_support</lifecycle>
</webscript>

Comment: What filename have you given that though?

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting your webscript using a deferent method than the one defined by the naming of your webscript artifacts :

```
<name>.<method>.<extension>
```

Note that the method used in that name pattern should be the one using while accessing the webscript! (get, post, put, delete...)

Comment: Also if that is a webscript with DELETE method and if you try to call the webscript from browser it will give a response of 405, as the browser by default calls GET. Try calling those webscripts with some REST client such as POSTMAN (addon for chrome).